# How do I use ServiceLoader in a Netbeans Platform project to add SPIs

Tags: java, netbeans, wrapper, netbeans-platform, netbeans-8

I'm trying to add MP3 capabilities to my Netbeans Platform project in Netbeans 8.0. I understand that this can be easily added to the javax.sound.sampled libraries using ServiceLoader and an SPI for the MP3 codecs.

So I downloaded [MP3 SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) and unzipped it, then in Netbeans I created a Jar wrapper module with the three jars that were in the zip file (one jar was in the root of the zip and two were under `lib/`). Then I made the modules that need the MP3 functionality depend on this wrapper module. But when I call `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` in those modules, "MP3" is not one of the types (only "WAVE", "AU" and "AIFF")

What am I missing?

I checked that the correct files are listed under `META-INF/services` in the main jar.

do I need to recreate the `lib/` structure in my wrapper module? Does it make a difference what code-base I use for the wrapper module? Do I need to alert the ServiceLoader somehow in my code?

Here is the project metadata for the wrapper module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1">
    <type>org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.project</type>
    <configuration>
        <data xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/nb-module-project/3">
            <code-name-base>org.sil.wrapper.mp3spi</code-name-base>
            <suite-component/>
            <module-dependencies/>
            <public-packages>
                <package>javazoom.jl.converter</package>
                <package>javazoom.jl.decoder</package>
                <package>javazoom.jl.player</package>
                <package>javazoom.jl.player.advanced</package>
                <package>javazoom.spi</package>
                <package>javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.convert</package>
                <package>javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file</package>
                <package>javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.tag</package>
                <package>org.tritonus.share</package>
                <package>org.tritonus.share.midi</package>
                <package>org.tritonus.share.sampled</package>
                <package>org.tritonus.share.sampled.convert</package>
                <package>org.tritonus.share.sampled.file</package>
                <package>org.tritonus.share.sampled.mixer</package>
            </public-packages>
            <class-path-extension>
                <runtime-relative-path>ext/mp3spi1.9.5.jar</runtime-relative-path>
                <binary-origin>release/modules/ext/mp3spi1.9.5.jar</binary-origin>
            </class-path-extension>
            <class-path-extension>
                <runtime-relative-path>ext/tritonus_share.jar</runtime-relative-path>
                <binary-origin>release/modules/ext/tritonus_share.jar</binary-origin>
            </class-path-extension>
            <class-path-extension>
                <runtime-relative-path>ext/jl1.0.1.jar</runtime-relative-path>
                <binary-origin>release/modules/ext/jl1.0.1.jar</binary-origin>
            </class-path-extension>
        </data>
    </configuration>
</project>
```

Comment: Perhaps I should also mention that I'm using Ubuntu, if that makes a difference, though I want the final distributable to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the SPI is working fine. It can read and play an MP3 file. However `AudioSystem.getAudioFileTypes()` lists file types that are writable, and the SPI doesn't provide the ability to write MP3 files. It doesn't include a provider for `javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileWriter`